# Typo3 8.7.19 Extension migration. Error: Could not analyse class

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I'm trying to migrate an old extension from 6.2.31 to 8.7.19. I can activate the Extension but trying to use it, the following Error occures:

## 1289386765: Could not analyse class: "TYPO3...\Controller\VideoController" maybe not loaded or no autoloader? Class TYPO3...\Controller\VideoController does not exist

I already checked if the Controller exists in the Extension/ cleared all chaches/ changed to full pathes in ext_localconf/ checked if Template-, Partial- and Layoutfiles beginning with a capital letter(i read that this is necessery since 8.7.x) / defined an autoload definition in ext_emconf.php

Nothing could help me fix the Problem. What else can i do?

Edit:
It is a Plug-in and the VideoController is there for interact with a video collection.

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'TYPO3.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'videofrontend',
    array(
        'FrontendVideo' => 'list,
        show,
        filter,
        listSelectedPublic,
        listSelectedMember,
        search,
        switchWatchedVideosStatusByAjax,incrementVideoCounterByAjax',
        'SelftestEvaluation' => 'evaluateSelftest',
    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
         'FrontendVideo' => 'list,
         show,
         filter,
         listSelectedPublic,
         listSelectedMember,
         search,
         switchWatchedVideosStatusByAjax, incrementVideoCounterByAjax',
        'SelftestEvaluation' => 'evaluateSelftest',
    )
);
```

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
$_EXTKEY,
'Videofrontend',
'video verwaltung' );
```

Directory-Structure

```
typo3conf
  /ext
    /ivw
      /Classes
        /Controller
          /VideoController.php
```

Namespace and Classname

```
namespace TYPO3\Videoverwaltung\Controller;

class VideoController extends 
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{…
```

Comment: This could be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239226/could-not-analyse-class-maybe-not-loaded-or-no-autoloader

Comment: This isn't enough information to give an informed answer. Can you add how this controller is used? If it's a plugin, add the information you use in \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin and \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin. Also, can you add the directory structure and filename, namespace and classname for your controller?

Comment: Try to deinstall extension and install again with extension manager in backend. This clear all caches and create autoload list again.